# Align and format text according to plots in R Shiny

Tags: css, r, shiny

I would like to add descriptive text to my plots in Shiny. I am outputting a dynamic number of plots in two columns and I would like to add a third column, like so:

[image: Example]

However, I can't figure out how to align the text with the plots. Can I use CSS containers or div's? HTML codes are working, but hardcoding a bunch of `<br/>`'s does not seem smart. [Here](https://bgbrink.shinyapps.io/Test/) is a minimal example.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `textOutpu` of course only prints the text as is. You should probably try `renderUI` together with `HTML()`

Comment: Right! My bad. I updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the `htmlOutput` line to

```
htmlOutput(plotname, style="height:400px;")
```

You can use the `Inspect Element` context menu of Firefox to find out the height for the plots.